# what will happen to ethereum mining after next fork

Tags: solo-mining

**I would like to ask what will be the future of GPU mining  after the next fork and change to be Prove to Stake**

Comment: Or this one: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/71/will-a-gpu-help-with-proof-of-stake

Answer (score 0):

There will be other altcoins to mine with a GPU, but not Ethereum.

GPU's will be totally useless in Ethereum's mining process after the fork.

> PoS happens by a miner putting up a stake, or locking up an amount of their coins, to verify a block of transactions. The cryptographic calculations in PoS are much simpler for computers to solve: you only need to prove you own a certain percentage of all coins available in a given currency. For example, if you somehow owned 2% of all Ether (ETH), you’d be able to mine 2% of all transactions across Ethereum.

It's all about how much you own ( stake. ).

See more about it here as to why Ethereum decides to change it to POS., https://www.ethnews.com/proof-of-work-vs-proof-of-stake-explained

This site displays all the Altcoins which are mineable using GPU's.

https://whattomine.com/